Backend WebSocket server causes client page to refresh unexpectedly
I'm working on a radio web project that streams radio stations through a web interface. The backend, written in Python, uses WebSockets to receive messages from the client and returns the currently playing song using Shazam's API. The setup works fine, except that my backend is causing the client page to refresh unexpectedly, even though no data is being sent back to the client.
The expected behavior is:
first, the client sends a radio station name to the WebSocket server.
Then The server processes the radio stream, identifies the song using Shazam, and prints the result.
However, when I run the backend with the song identification function (result = await songInfo(message)), the client page refreshes without me sending anything back to the client.
this is my backend
async def identify_song(audio_name: str):
    audio_url = dict[audio_name]
    audio_file_place = fr".\backend\{audio_name}.mp3"
    if os.path.exists(audio_file_place):
        os.remove(audio_file_place)

    stream = ffmpeg.input(audio_url, t=10)
    stream.output(audio_file_place).run()

    shazam = Shazam()
    out = await shazam.recognize(audio_file_place)
    
    if out['matches']:
        #info...
        
        return {
            #...
        }
    return None


async def songInfo(radio_name):
    result = await identify_song(radio_name)
    return result

async def server(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        print(message)
        result = await songInfo(message)
        print(result)

run_server = websockets.serve(server, "localhost", 5000)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

I found that removing result = await songInfo(message) stops the client from refreshing, which points to that line causing the issue.
This is an example of my server output:
INFO:websockets.server:connection open
glglz
ffmpeg version N-116617-g9e3b5b8a26-20240813 ...
...
INFO:websockets.server:connection open
INFO:websockets.server:connection open
ERROR:websockets.server:connection handler failed
INFO:websockets.server:connection closed
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: no close frame received or sent
{'title': '...', 'subtitle': '...', '...': '...', 'href': '...'} #print(result)
#connection open/closed few more times

Why is my WebSocket server causing the client page to refresh when I call the song identification function, and how can I prevent this from happening while keeping the song identification functionality intact?
